# How to connect Google Data Studio to GCP Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

In the instructions to connect Google Data Studio to a PostGres DB it says you must whitelist these 3 IP's

142.251.74.0/23

2001:4860:4807::/48

74.125.0.0/16

The problem is the second one.  GCP will not allow a IPV6 address in it's allowed connections.

[SCREENSHOT:  GCP Postgres Instance, allowed connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0dxf.jpg)

Comment: Where are those instructions from?

Comment: Bottom of the article under Firewall
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Answer (score -1):

I think it should work with just the ipv4s.